# Counting treetops from the DSM

Tags: qgis, dem, photogrammetry

I want to measure tree heights in the forest using drone photogrammetry.  So far it's easy to measure single trees height using fugroviewer in the pointcloud, but I would really like to measure whole groups of trees.

This picture below represents the tops. Is there a way to spot them out into the attribute table?

[image: The tops of the trees]

This is another image from before the treetops has been isolated.
[image]

I'm not a big GIS expert, so please be really specific in your explanation, if you have an idea.

Comment: The title of your question is about COUNTING tree tops then your question is about MEASURING height, edit your title/question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: have you ever tried fusion (http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html) it can calculate tree heights and bare earth dem. It then uses those to create points and polygon representing individual trees with heights.